# Building a 36er bike

Tags: mountain-bike, frames, fork

I'm casually researching building a 36er bike, preferably mountainbike style. I'm looking for the experience of others on this. I would like to own it more for curiosity sake than any other, but would still like it to ride reasonably well and not be ridiculously heavy.

Are there any frame builders in the US who can put together a decent alloy frame and fork to get me started on this project? Any experiences from others who have tried or succeeded in doing this?

Comment: I'd think you'd need to be at least 6.5 feet and probably closer to 7 feet tall to ride a 36er. At that point, you're probably in the NBA, so you could commission pretty much anything you want. I saw something called the "dirty sixer" on a forum once though. As for not ridiculously heavy, at that size I don't think you have a choice.

Comment: Where do you find tires and wheels for such a thing?

Comment: http://www.bikerumor.com/2013/04/26/soc13-dirty-sixer-builds-36-wheeled-mtbs-for-the-exceptionally-tall/ seems to be the bike I saw on a forum. Looks like a custom job (though thats not surprising - you didn't have much choice for rims for something like a Pugsley other than QBP until recently as well).

Comment: Looks like a dedicated [blog](http://36ers.wordpress.com/) is available

Answer (score 2):

There was an article in the CTC magazine recently about a guy who'd built one. Their website has a [FAQ](http://www.pimcycles.co.uk/36er-faq/) which might be of interest.

Details include:

- Tyres/tubes from unicycles
- Needed very large disk rotors to make it stop 203mm.
- Claimed to fit people of 5ft 3in to 6ft 5in (yes, I was surprised).

Also, I've spotted an [example here](http://bmxmuseum.com/forums/viewtopic.php?id=163676) which looks a lot like the picture in the magazine.

Answer (score 0):

Check out [Directory Of Custom American Handmade Road Bike Frame Builders](http://cyclophiliac.com/american-custom-handmade-road-bike-frame-builders/).

You can also try [Framebuilders](https://groups.google.com/forum/m/#!forum/framebuilders) on Google groups.

Good luck with your project!